# Tone Generator With SoundFonts in Xcode, Is It Possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, soundfont, tone-generator

I am creating a musical app which needs to generate musical notes. The app needs the ability to produce pitches that sound like realistic instrument based on changing input from the user. These pitches could also be between note (ex. Ab 5 cents flat).
I have searched and found a tone generator tutorial however nothing including soundfonts. Any help would be appreciated.

Tone Generator Tutorial - https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html

Comment: Sure, you can use a midi player object to generate tones from a soundfont.

Comment: @matt Is possible to use midi to play a specified note flat or sharp? There is this midi tutorial - https://rollout.io/blog/building-a-midi-music-app-for-ios-in-swift/ However it doesn't mention the ability to play a note flat or sharp, and I'm unable to find anything helpful in apple's documentation

Comment: There's some way to bend the note in MIDI but that's a MIDI question. :) (I know this because I've heard MIDI files tuned in various older temperaments.)